# Deleted email associated with Steam, can't access account

Tags: steam

I deleted the address associated with my steam account. Now i cannot access it so I can change the email to my new one. Does anyone know how to change the email without being logged in, or if not, a way to bypass the Steam email authentication? Thanks in advance. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can visit https://help.steampowered.com/wizard/HelpWithLogin, indicate you can't receive your Steam Guard codes, select "verify and update my email address", then follow the wizard as long as possible. You'll need one of the following (although I didn't try to go all the way on my own account):

1. Steam Guard using the mobile app;
2. A phone number linked to your account;
3. your password (and possibly secret questions, I didn't try any further).

If you can't get any further, you will have to contact Steam support. Be sure to have at least one credit card number used to buy your games; Steam support will use that to restore access.

Answer (score 0):

To restore access to your Steam account, support actually asks for a credit card number used to purchase your games.

All your other information is secondary.  Steam clearly states you cannot sell an account, so the ability to restore access using only your purchase history fully aligns with their ToS.